How is it possible to import a class or module from the Main project to a SPM package dependency?
I'm currently working on an iOS app using Xcode and Swift. I've added an open-source dependency to my project via Swift Package Manager (SPM). I need to make some changes to the code in the dependency and access a global variable (in this case, the logger) from the main project. The issue is that the dependency doesn't have direct access to the project. I'm wondering how I can make this possible.

@JoakimDanielson that's called a "circular dependency", which isn't allowed and will lead to a compiler error. A circular dependency cannot compile as it's impossible for the compiler to compile either module without its dependency, but since there's a circular dependency, no module can be compiled, since some of its dependencies depend on the module itself.

I don't think you should, if I understand you correctly you want to create a situation where the app module depends on a package and the package depends on the app module but you must always avoid such circular dependencies in your architecture since the compiler will not allow for it between modules. If you really need to access something in the app module then move the affected code back from the package to the app module.

You're probably right, and it's not a good idea. I just wanted to ensure that I was not possible and that I did not repeat code in both projects.

You can move the logger into a separate package. Then you can import it from Main and other dependencies. Note also, when you use OSLog, you should not wrap the OSLog functions in your own.

sorry, but what do you mean by not wrapping the OSLog functions on your own? thanks

You need create some configuration possibility for you package. Then you will configure it from main project.
